# CMake: Enforcing Execution Order between Sibling Target Dependencies

Tags: cmake

I would like to enforce the execution order of sibling dependencies. Let's assume we have the following top-level targets:

```
add_custom_target(test_all)
add_custom_target(test_coverage)
add_custom_target(test_coverage_zero)
add_custom_target(test_coverage_collect)
```

I'm using `test_all` to execute unit tests (and possibly build them and their dependencies). `test_coverage` should execute `test_coverage_zero`, then `test_all`, and finally `test_coverage_collect`. `test_coverage_zero` will cleanup leftover coverage data from a previous run of `test_all`, while `test_coverage_collect` uses the current coverage data and produces some kind human-readable output. The reason for this setup is to allow `test_all` to be executed without actual coverage data processing. On the other hand `test_coverage` needs to execute `test_all` to produce coverage data.

*[Detail: I'm using `gcov`/`lcov` for the coverage data and added custom commands to `test_coverage_zero` and `test_coverage_collect` for the actual processing.]*

I've setup the following dependencies to achieve this behavior:

```
add_dependencies(test_coverage test_coverage_zero test_all test_coverage_collect)
```

That does not work. The actual execution order is `test_all`, `test_coverage_zero`, and `test_coverage_collect`, which removes the coverage data before the collection step.

My question: How do I enforce the order of target dependencies (on the sibling level) in CMake?

Comment: Add additional dependencies between the siblings?

Comment: @usr1234567: tried that, doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Can you please give the actual `COMMAND` parts for your targets? Just from looking at it I don't think you need the `test_coverage_zero` and `test_coverage_collect` targets if you work with [`add_custom_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_custom_command.html) calls and give the correct `OUTPUT` and `DEPENDS` files.

Comment: @Florian: i'd like to avoid file dependencies because then i need to gather those somehow; all i want is to _enforce_ a certain order based on top-level target dependencies. but see my answer after some playing around.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is:

```
add_dependencies(test_all              test_coverage_zero)
add_dependencies(test_coverage_collect test_all)
add_dependencies(test_coverage         test_coverage_zero test_all test_coverage_collect)
```

However, removing either `test_coverage_zero` or `test_all` from the last dependency will also not work, even though there's a clear dependency chain `test_coverage`<-`test_coverage_collect`<-`test_all`<-`test_coverage_zero`.